# Clang error on GMP memory management functions

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, gmp

I have some code that uses GMP which compiles and runs fine with g++.

```
...
// get ptrs to GMP memory management functions
void *(*alloc_func_ptr) (size_t);
void *(*free_func_ptr) (void *, size_t);
mp_get_memory_functions(&alloc_func_ptr, NULL, &free_func_ptr);
...
```

But when i compile it with the most recent clang++ it throws this error

```
gmpxx_boost_serialization.h:127: error: no matching function for call to '__gmp_get_memory_functions'
mp_get_memory_functions(&alloc_func_ptr, NULL, &free_func_ptr);
```

where **mp_get_memory_functions** is a macro

```
#define mp_get_memory_functions __gmp_get_memory_functions
__GMP_DECLSPEC void mp_get_memory_functions (void *(**) (size_t),
                  void *(**) (void *, size_t, size_t),
                  void (**) (void *, size_t)) __GMP_NOTHROW;
```

Why does clang complain?

Comment: Hard to say from what you have posted. Is `mp_get_memory_functions` a macro? If so, what does it expand to? Is there a `_gmp_get_memory_functions` declared, and if so, what is it declared as?

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes,and i added that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing:

```
void *(*free_func_ptr) (void *, size_t);
```

to:

```
void (*free_func_ptr) (void *, size_t);
```

As per the declaration, third argument to "mp_get_memory_functions" is address of the function pointer ( to function which returns "void" and not "void *" )

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you very much @Icarus3 .I wonder why it worked with g++.

Comment: @danieltorres g++ also refuse to compile your original code for me. With `-fpermissive` you can downgrade the error to a warning, but it still complains.

Comment: yes, I just tried simple program and g++ does produce error.

Comment: weird. I am using g++-4.8 , and even with --pedantic it doesnt show any warning related with that.